# How to write files in specific order?

Tags: rsync

Okay, here's a weird problem -- My wife just bought a 2014 Nissan Altima.  So, I took her iTunes library and converted the .m4a files to .mp3, since the car audio system only supports .mp3 and .wma.  So far so good.  Then I copied the files to a DOS FAT-32 formatted USB thumb drive, and connected the drive to the car's USB port, only to find all of the tracks were out of sequence.  All tracks begin with a two digit numeric prefix, i.e., 01, 02, 03, etc.  So you would think they would be in order.  So I called Nissan Connect support and the rep told me that there is a known problem with reading files in the correct order.  He said the files are read in the same order they are written.  So, I manually copied a few albums with the tracks in a predetermined order, and sure enough he was correct.

So I copied about 6 albums for testing, then changed to the top level directory and did a "find . >music.txt".  Then I passed this file to rsync like this:

```
rsync -av --files-from=music.txt . ../Marys\ Music\ Sequenced/
```

The files looked like they were copied in order, but when I listed the files in order of modified time, they were in the same sequence as the original files:

```
../Marys Music Sequenced/Air Supply/Air Supply Greatest Hits> ls -1rt
01 Lost In Love.mp3
04 Every Woman In The World.mp3
03 Chances.mp3
02 All Out Of Love.mp3
06 Here I Am (Just When I Thought I Was Over You).mp3
05 The One That You Love.mp3
08 I Want To Give It All.mp3
07 Sweet Dreams.mp3
11 Young Love.mp3
```

So the question is, how can I copy files listed in a file named music.txt, and copy them to a destination, and ensure the modification times are in the same sequence as the files are listed?

Answer (score 6):

You asked two question, one clearly stated and one only implicitly:

1. How can I copy files listed in a file named music.txt, and copy them to a destination, and ensure the modification times are in the same sequence as the files are listed?
2. How can I achieve that my MP3 player reads the files in alphabetical order from an USB stick (formatted with FAT filesystem)?

But IMHO the second one is your real one. I think, the Nissan guy sent you on the wrong track. (See [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem))

But enough prattled... now I try to answer both questions:

1. Your `rsync` approach is nearly the solution to the first question, *only* you used the `-a` parameter. Rsync's `-a` is equivalent to `-rlptgoD`, which especially includes `-t`:

   > *man rsync (...)*
   >
   > This tells rsync to transfer modification times along with the files and update them on the remote system.

   Definitely not what you want. As you copy to a FAT filesystem (whicht neither support owner, groups, permission, links, etc.) I see no good reason for most of the other options provided by `-a` at all, so try

   ```
   rsync -rv --files-from=music.txt . ../Marys\ Music\ Sequenced/
   ```
2. To get your MP3 files read in alphabetical order I suggest another approach. I doubt that *the files are read in the same order they are written* as stated by the Nissan technician, but instead **in the order they are listed in the file allocation table**. And exactly for rearranging that order there is a neat tool, called [fatsort](http://fatsort.sourceforge.net/).

   First, make sure your USB stick is **not** mounted and find the corresponding device (e.g. using `cat /proc/partitions`), lets say it is `/dev/sdi1`. Then run fatsort:

   ```
   fatsort -cn /dev/sdi1
   ```

   This sorts the file entries *case insensitive* and in so called *natural order*, which includes alphabetically order.<sup>1)</sup>

   It's very fast and you do not need to copy all files over and over again, if you add only one other file.

---

<sup>1)</sup> I cannot test the command right now, but if I remember correctly, `-n` is what you want. If not, please consult the help (`fatsort -h`) yourself.

Comment: 9 years later, and this saved me trouble with a 2012 Camry.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could be done with xargs:

```
cat music.txt | xargs -I% rsync -av "./%" "../Marys\ Music\ Sequenced/%"
```

An alternative would be to do something like this (assuming everything is sequential):

```
ls "../Marys\ Music\ Sequenced/" | xargs -I% touch "%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something like this?

```
copy files
for each file in music.txt
    touch destination file
    sleep 1
```